# Api response structure with configurable columns definitions

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture, api-design

I am building an application for a student application system which allows multiple organisations to provide an online application form to its students to apply for courses.
For each application, it will have ID, StudentName, CourseName. However some universities require SecondaryExamMark and some requires Reference name and reference contact no.

I am making an API call (/application/list?pageNo=1&rowsPerPage=20&orgId=1)
and returns all application data with common information plus the extra requirements based on the organisation id provided

I defined an application model that includes all common properties plus a subset of properties all organisations requested and store them in a single database table with a few nullable fields for different organisation.

In terms of the Api response structure, which of the following is more appropriate?

```
{
    ID: 1,
    StudentName: 'A B',
    CourseName: 'B C',
    ReferenceName: null,
    ReferenceContact: null,
    SecondarySchoolMark: '80'
}
```

OR

```
{
    headers: [
        {
            Title: "ID",
            Type: "text"
        },
        {
            Title: "StudentName",
            Type: "text"
        },
        {
            Title: "CourseName",
            Type: "text"
        },
        {
            Title: "SecondarySchoolMark",
            Type: "text"
        }
    ],
    application: [
        {
            Title: "ID",
            Value: "12345"
        },
        {
            Title: "StudentName",
            Value: "A B"
        },
        {
            Title: "CourseName",
            Value: 'B C'
        }
        {
            Title: 'SecondarySchoolMark',
            Value: '80'
        }
    ]
}
```

The first approach seems to be a general Api structure which returns an object that describes an application. However the second approach allows the Api to decide which columns should be rendered, and UI would only have to treat the response as display fields.

IMO, i would prefer the first approach because in order to make the API integrate-able with other clients, the API should provide resource based responses. And showing or hiding the columns (whether based on another Api call to /getdisplaycolumns?orgId=1 or just treat null columns as hidden is UI's responsibility)

**Edit 1**: not necessarily returning the null properties from the approach one as Json serializer allows to ignore null properties)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, settling on a model (resource) that has a couple of nullable properties that the client can ignore sounds like a more robust design (strongly typed properties!) than deserializing whatever the second model is into a Dictionary of sorts and working with that.